# rbenv doesn't have the ruby version and the ruby-build plugs directory doesn't exist, what to do?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ruby-build

rbenv doesn't show the newer versions of Ruby.
Various guides say to update ruby build but I don't have the ruby-build directory set up to do that in my installation.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

Follow these steps:

```
# confirm version NOT available
$ rbenv install --list | grep 2.6.2
# Nothing shows up

$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

$ rbenv install --list | grep 2.6.2
2.6.2 # <-- Now it shows up !
```

Now that version can be installed locally

```
$ rbenv install 2.6.2
$ ruby -v
$ ruby 2.6.2p47
```

One final step I had to do was

```
$ bundle # -> this gave an error "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile."
$ gem install bundler:2.0.1
```

Finally, a

```
$ bundle
```

for a project with a `.ruby-version` file of `2.6.2` will work !

Comment: And after you do the initial setup of `ruby-build`, you can update it by running `git pull origin master` from the `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build` directory anytime you want to get newer versions.